# AM/PM is not working in django HTML template

Tags: django

When I am using AM/PM, I am getting an error.

> Enter a valid date/time.

But without using AM/PM, I am not getting any errors. I am using `Bootstrap-DateTimepicker` in my HTML template.

Here is my code:

**froms.py**

```py
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = Blog
        fields = ['title','body','published']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder': 'Title'}),
                   'published': forms.DateTimeInput(format=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'])}
```

**HTML File**

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{from}}
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a', 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you try to provide the format by setting the format for the *widget* i.e. `DateTimeInput`, but the problem is that this format will only be used for the *initial* value of the input and it is not used to parse the submitted values. Instead you also want to pass the `input_formats` kwarg to the *form field* i.e. [`DateTimeField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield).

Also your format seems to be missing the seconds that you set in the javascript? You might need to add `%S` in the format string in that case:

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    published = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'],
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['title','body','published']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder': 'Title'}),
        }
```

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat I have a question if I use `forms.Form` then will I only use `published = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'])` should I use DateTimeInput in widget? If I don't use ModelForm.

Comment: @boyenec Oh wait, since you are defining the field manually the widget specified in the `Meta` will not be used. You will have to specify it in the form field, edited my answer.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat your previous solution worked but the new solution didn't work. getting this error  `strftime() argument 1 must be str, not list` we need to be remove one list. After remove one list, `input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'],
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')` it worked

Comment: @boyenec ah, yes didn't notice you had set `format` to a list. `input_formats` can be a list but the widgets `format` argument must be a string since it is used to format the initial value of the input field.